# Is it possible to 'project' specific fields from a jsonb object in postrgesql?

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm looking for the equivalent of '$project' from mongodb in postgres json handling functions

I have a large json object, and I want to select a number of fields from it.
the specific fields name are dynamic so i'm looking for a solution that will not include hard coding them

for example, given object like:

```
{
'a':...
'b':...
'c':...
'd':...
}
```

a statement like

```
select json_project(data, ['a','b'])
from table
```

should return

```
{
'a':...
'b':...
}
```

where the list of fields should be a parameter

Comment: the result should be a json like or just rows?

Comment: preferably json.
a row with different columns is also fine.
different rows (like when using json_each) is the least wanted

Answer (score 1):

This should do it (untested):

```
CREATE FUNCTION json_project(doc json, keys json) RETURN json AS $$
  SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(d.key, d.value))
  FROM json_each(doc) d
  JOIN json_array_elements(keys) k ON k.value = d.key;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

The trick is to break up the `json` doc into its key (text) and value (scalar or a more complex json document), then `JOIN` that to the keys contained in the exploded parameter array, and finally aggregate the matches into a new `json` document.

Note that if you are working with the `jsonb` type, all functions should be invoked with the `jsonb_*` variant.

Comment: The problem I see here is that you need to pass a json as key and that is not what the OP wants. I think if you change the second parameter into  varchar array and use the unnest function it would be good

Comment: @JorgeCampos The OP is not specific about that (although the single quotes suggest an array) but seeing that MongoDB uses `json` throughout passing the keys of interest as a `json` document seems to make sense. But it would work equally well with an array and `unnest()` instead of `json_array_elements()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION json_project(jsondata jsonb, jsonfields varchar) RETURNS json 
AS $$
declare
  newJson varchar;
  cs record;
BEGIN
    newJson := '{';
    for cs in (select key, value 
         from json_each(jsondata::json)
        where key in (select * from unnest(string_to_array(jsonfields,','))) ) loop
    if newJson != '{' then
        newJson := newJson || ',';
    end if;
    newJson := newJson || '"'||cs.key||'"'||':'||cs.value;
    end loop;
    newJson := newJson || '}';

    RETURN newJson::jsonb;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And if you run it as:

```
select json_project( '{"a":"someAvalue", "b":"someBvalue", "c":1, "d":"someDvalue" }', 
                     'a,c' );
```

You will get

```
{"a": "someAvalue", "c": 1}
```